# MapReduce program for comparing of hive output and a flat file

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I want to compare a flat file with hive output.

Example::

```
Hive> select * from hive_table;
abcd,1234
def,456
```

and a flat file contains::

```
abcd,1234
def,456
```

So, I want to compare both of this with columns and rows for validation.

Comment: Store both the columns from (Hive and flat file)in a seperate list or Map. And then compare those list or Map

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
List<String> hiveList = new ArrayList<String>(); // add all the output of Hive into the List
        hiveList.add("abcd,1234");
        hiveList.add("def,456");

        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); // add all the data from file into the List
        arrayList.add("abcd,1234");
        arrayList.add("def,456");

        if(hiveList.containsAll(arrayList)) // even a single space value changed this will be false
        {
            System.out.println("Contains");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Contains");
        }
```